# How to Solve Summation Notation

Tags: summation

I am having trouble with this equation in a class I am taking and I am trying to understand it: $$\sum_{i=47}^{i=136} M_i$$

We have to solve for the problem below but the hint our professor gave us was subtraction.  I am confused because it is my understanding that the bottom was the starting point and the top was the ending point.  So wouldn't $M_i$ start with $M_{47}$ and work up from there?  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How is $M_i$ defined? We don't have enough information to answer otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The summation can be rewritten as:

$$\sum_{i=47}^{i=136} M_i =\sum_{i=0}^{i=136} M_i - \sum_{i=0}^{i=46} M_i$$

The reason behind this is that the when summing from $i=0$ to $i=136$ we would be also including all $M_i$ from $i=0$ to $i=46$. We can then use subtract the sum of all numbers in that range to get the final result.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the explanation there!  I really do appreciate it.  So he is stating to find that summation.  Would that rewritten summation be the answer at that point?  I apologize I am struggling a little to understand this stuff lol.

Comment: He probably wants you to calculate the value of the rewritten summation which I can't do without knowing what $M_i$ is defined as. 

The rewriting helps because depending on what your $M_i$ means it is probably easier to calculate the sum from 0 to 136 and 0 to 46 and subtracting than the alternative. Also the bottom of the summation may make more sense as $i=1$.

Comment: Well, that is the issue, he does not define or give a value for M.  Which is part of why I was confused in the first place haha.

Comment: Maybe he means $M_i=I$, so it be (47+48+49...136)? This would be where the simplification of 2 sums starting at 0 would help because there is a known formula for the sum of the first $n$ integers.

Comment: Yeah, I did not think of that.  So if that was the case, I would have (47, 48, 49...136) and then (1, 2, 3, 4...136) and then use the rewritten summation formula written above?

Comment: It would be like this: (47 + 48 + 49...136) = (1 +2 + 3...136) - (1 +2 + 3...46). The rewrite is useful because there is a known simple formula for summing the first n numbers, but this is most relevant if you would have been expected to be exposed to it in or before your class: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_⋯

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the summation you are given is over the sequence 47, 48, 49, $\dots$, 136.

You are probably used to summation formulas that start with 1.  So can you rewrite the given summation in terms of those familiar ones?
$$
    \sum_{i=47}^{136} M_i = \sum_{i=1}^{?} M_i - \sum_{i=1}^{?} M_i
$$

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what $M_i$ is, I can only guess that he might be suggesting that you do $$\sum_{i=47}^{i=136} M_i = \sum _{i=0}^{i=136} M_i - \sum_{i=0}^{i=46}M_i $$